# Return text when checkbox selected

Tags: javascript

In my site, I have a form that users can click on a checkbox to select "available". I want to have "Yes" or "No" returned in the displayArticle function based on whether the box is checked or not. Right now it returns True or False, which is not optimal. How can I code this?

Here is my entire JS code:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: 0x0,
  loading: false,

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    // initialize web3
    if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      //reuse the provider of the Web3 object injected by Metamask
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      //create a new provider and plug it directly into our local node
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    App.displayAccountInfo();

    return App.initContract();
  },

  displayAccountInfo: function() {
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if(err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $('#account').text(account);
        web3.eth.getBalance(account, function(err, balance) {
          if(err === null) {
            $('#accountBalance').text(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
          }
        })
      }
    });
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('RentalContract.json', function(chainListArtifact) {
      //added May24 to json file name
      // get the contract artifact file and use it to instantiate a truffle contract abstraction
      App.contracts.RentalContract = TruffleContract(chainListArtifact);
      // set the provider for our contracts
      App.contracts.RentalContract.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
      // listen to events
      App.listenToEvents();
      // retrieve the article from the contract
      return App.reloadArticles();
    });
  },

  reloadArticles: function() {
    //avoid reentry bugs
    if(App.loading){
      return;
    }
    App.loading = true;

    // refresh account information because the balance might have changed
    App.displayAccountInfo();

    var chainListInstance;

    App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      chainListInstance = instance;
      return chainListInstance.getArticlesForSale();
    }).then(function(articlesIds) {

      // retrieve the article placeholder and clear it
      $('#articlesRow').empty();

      for(var i = 0; i < articlesIds.length; i++){
        var articleId = articlesIds[i];
        chainListInstance.articles(articleId.toNumber()).then(function(article){
          App.displayArticle(article[0], article[1], article[3], article[4], article[5], article[6], article[7]);
        });
      }
      App.loading = false;

    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      App.loading = false;
    });
  },

  //displayArticle: function(id, seller, beds, baths, propaddress, rental_price, property_type, description, available, contact_email) {
  displayArticle: function(id, seller, propaddress, rental_price, description, available, contact) {
    var articlesRow = $('#articlesRow');

    //var etherPrice = web3.fromWei(price, "ether");

    var articleTemplate = $("#articleTemplate");
    //articleTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(propaddress);
    //articleTemplate.find('.beds').text(beds);
    //articleTemplate.find('.baths').text(baths);
    articleTemplate.find('.propaddress').text(propaddress);
    articleTemplate.find('.rental_price').text('$' + rental_price);
    //articleTemplate.find('.property_type').text(property_type);
    articleTemplate.find('.description').text(description);
    articleTemplate.find('.available').text(available);
    articleTemplate.find('.contact').text(contact);
  //  articleTemplate.find('.article_price').text(etherPrice + " ETH");
    articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-id', id);
    // articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-value', etherPrice);

    //seller
    if(seller == App.account){
      articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text("You");
      articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').hide();
    }else{
      articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text(seller);
      articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').show();
    }
    //add this new article
    articlesRow.append(articleTemplate.html());
  },



  sellArticle: function() {
    // retrieve the detail of the article
  //  var _article_name = $('#article_name').val();
    var _description = $('#description').val();
    //var _beds = $('#beds').val();
    //var _baths = $('#baths').val();
    var _propaddress = $('#propaddress').val();
    var _rental_price = $('#rental_price').val();
    //var _property_type = $('#property_type').val();
    var _available = $('#available').val();
    var _contact = $('#contact').val();
  //  var _article_price = $('#article_price').val();
  //  var _price = web3.toWei(parseFloat($('#article_price').val() || 0), "ether");

//    if((_description.trim() == '') || (rental_price == 0)) {
      // nothing to sell
//      return false;
//    }

    App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      //return instance.sellArticle(_description, _beds, _baths, _propaddress, _rental_price, _property_type, _available, _contact_email, {
      return instance.sellArticle(_propaddress, _rental_price, _description, _available, _contact,{
          from: App.account,
        gas: 500000
      });
    }).then(function(result) {

    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  },

  // listen to events triggered by the contract
  listenToEvents: function() {
    App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      instance.LogSellArticle({}, {}).watch(function(error, event) {
        if (!error) {
          $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._propaddress + ' is now for sale</li>');
        } else {
          console.error(error);
        }
        App.reloadArticles();
      });

      instance.LogBuyArticle({}, {}).watch(function(error, event) {
        if (!error) {
          $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._buyer + ' bought ' + event.args._propaddress + '</li>');
        } else {
          console.error(error);
        }
        App.reloadArticles();
      });
    });
  },

  buyArticle: function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    // retrieve the article price and data
    var _articleId = $(event.target).data('id');
    var _price = parseFloat($(event.target).data('value'));

    App.contracts.RentalContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
      return instance.buyArticle(_articleId, {
        from: App.account,
        value: web3.toWei(_price, "ether"),
        gas: 500000
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

Comment: Explain: What's is your check box? And you're trying to get exactly?

Comment: I don't see anything that looks even remotely like a checkbox in that code.

Comment: The checkbox states: "Property is available for viewing:" The user checks the box if the property is available. Ideally, I want the result data to show: "Property is available for viewing" if the box is checked, and "Property is not available for viewing" if the box is not checked. Right now, the result is always the "yes" value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, perhaps this will work for you.

```
var isChecked = '';
if (articleTemplate.find('.available').checked === true)
{ isChecked = 'yes'} else
{ isChecked = 'no'}
.
.
.
return isChecked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
articleTemplate.find( '.available' ).text( available ? 'Yes' : 'No' );
```

**Example:**

```js
function returnValue() {
  $( '#val' ).text( $( '#chk' ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'Yes' : 'No' )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chk" onclick="returnValue()" />
<label for="chk">Available</label>
<h2 id="val"></h2>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not exactly sure where to add this code, so I have posted the code in my question. I have placed it (guessing), and I still don't get the result. Thanks if you can clarify.

Comment: Find this line `articleTemplate.find('.available').text(available);` in your code and replace it with `articleTemplate.find( '.available' ).text( available ? 'Yes' : 'No' );`